# difficuly in using merge function

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am getting syntax error with the `.merge()` Pandas function.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Below is a snippet of my code;

```
df2 = df2.merge(df1[list('col1','col2'], on ='ABC')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`str.zfill(width)`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_zfill.htm):

> The method zfill() pads string on the left with zeros to fill width.
>
> **width** − This is final width of the string. This is the width which we
>   would get after filling zeros.

```
id = [6, 77, 888, 9999]
print([str(x).zfill(4) for x in id])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['0006', '0077', '0888', '9999']
```

**EDIT**:

To convert the column values in a column using list-comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'un-padded':[6, 77, 888, 9999]})
df['padded'] = [str(x).zfill(4) for x in df['un-padded']]
print(df)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
   un-padded padded
0          6   0006
1         77   0077
2        888   0888
3       9999   9999
```

Comment: I have one column containing thousands of such ID and need to insert a new column using zfill(). How can I do that?

Comment: @Pradeep added an edit for it :)

Comment: This is my first python code so I might be asking too silly things. 

import csv

with open('example.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    with open ('new_'+csvfile, 'w') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter =',')
        writer.writerow(next(reader) + ['New-column']

After this I need to use zfill to insert new values which are there in xyz column. Could you help me to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a string formatting for that:

```
>>> for n in (9, 99, 999, 9999):
...     print(f"{n:0>4}")
... 
0009
0099
0999
9999
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.zfill(x)` will put x zeroes before any string

If you'd rather use string formatting, `f'{str:0x}'` also works.

P.S. Don't name your strings `str` as it overloads the `str` class

Comment: I think this is more Pythonic than string formatting, especially C-style formatting.

Comment: I consider this less readable.  I do prefer the new string formatting style to the old 'C style'.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to treat it as a string value, as numeric values can't have leading zeros.  To create a 0-padded string of length 4, you can do this:

```
v = 4
print("{:04d}".format(v))
```

or the older style:

```
v = 4
print("%04d" % v)
```

Result either way:

```
0004
```

Answer (score 0):

String formatting is the answer.

```
print('%04d' % 4)
0004
print('%04d' % 43)
0043
```